# Why kivy mapview seem to be an error itself on android?

Tags: python, kivy, logcat, buildozer

I am trying to make an app using `kivy garden's mapview` and my app actually work on computers, compile and gets deployed but when the app runs, it instantly close and `logcat` says that the error is

`KeyError: 'kivy.garden.mapview'`

on lines like

`from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView`.

It seems to be a quite recent error since I'm not the only one to have this problem but solutions I found seem to be outdated like adding `garden_requirements = mapview` or `kivy_garden.mapview` in the requirements in the `buildozer.spec` file which I tried but doesn't work. The `buildozer.spec` file doesn't even have a line speaking about garden so I basically didn't modify it except for things like title and importing .txt files. I am running all of this on an Ubuntu virtual machine on which the program works and the exact same machine already made working kivy apps that were not using mapview. Someone asked the same question 5 months ago but doesn't seem to have found an answer yet:

https://johnnn.tech/q/i-am-getting-keyerror-kivy-garden-mapview-after-running-buildozer-android-debug-deploy-run-logcat-in-my-buildoer-file-i-had-no-garden_requirements/.

If you need any more information I will gladly provide it to you.

EDIT: The problem seems to be solvable by using the command `garden install mapview` so I just have to run this command on my phone app's environment somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `kivy_garden.mapview` as a module instead of using garden itself (the command `garden install mapview` + importing like `import kivy.garden.mapview`). The problem seems to come from a deprecated version problem.